# How to remove small camera preview box in artoolkit?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-camera, artoolkit

I'm using unity3d and ARToolkit to create an AR app. My question is when opening the application, a small camera preview box always shows in the upper left of the screen. Is there a way to remove this by editing UnityARPlayer.jar via android studio or the unity package itself?

Comment: It is already removed when you use ARToolKit6. In theory, it is possible to remove it in ARToolKit5 as well. It has to do with the loading of the ARToolKit core and the request of the video frame from Android. You would need to change the unity package and the UnityARPlayer.jar to do it. And create events that are sent to the .jar so that Android opens the camera after the scene is loaded and not up front.

Comment: Hi @Thor_Bux , can you guide me what is the exact function to change or update in UnityARPlayer.jar? Or should I follow this [repo](https://github.com/artoolkit/arunity5/pull/130)? Or there's a simple way? thanks

Comment: Yes, that repo is a good starting point. Just keep in mind that I personally never got it to work. On the other hand, you could just use ARToolKit6. It is solved there.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue **(just to hide the small camera, not to remove it completely!)**, you have to regenerate the UnityARPlayer.jar file after making a small correction in the UnityARPlayerActivity.java file available in the AndroidStudio project of ARToolkit 5.3.2 which is available [here](https://github.com/artoolkit/arunity5).

In the project, in the UnityARPlayer\src\main\java\org\artoolkit\ar\unity\UnityARPlayerActivity.java file, in the onResume() method, change the code

```
decorView.addView(previewView, new LayoutParams(128, 128));
```

to

```
decorView.addView(previewView, new LayoutParams(1, 1));
```

Here, we are just changing the camera preview size, to make it nearly invisible.